# Laravel, ошибка 500 при запуске файла

Tags: php, laravel

Я создал файл decrypt.php для расшифровки куки ларавела и передачи на другой сайт. Что мне нужно в него засунуть, чтобы этот скрипт заработал

```
$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class); 
$decryptedResult = $encrypter->decrypt('тут куки ларавела');
```

Если я его просто так вставляю, то выводит ошибку 500

Comment: А зачем файл отдельный? Что мешает роут создать? fatal error падает потому что файл не находит класс \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class

Comment: Не знаю как это сделать, никогда не работал с laravel. Можно как-то сделать это всё таки в отдельном файле в папке public?

Comment: _в отдельном файле в папке public?_ плохая идея

Comment: Как можно сделать лучше? Где разместить?

Comment: Изучайте Laravel чтобы понять где в ней вам нужно размещать код - в [web](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure) части, в [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan), или где-то еще, либо переосмыслите вопрос и отредактируйте его.